# Where does jQuery fit-in with frameworks like JavaScriptMVC, BackboneJS, SproutCore and Knockout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks

I have been happily using [**JQuery**](http://jquery.com/) for the last 2 years and have been quite sucessful creating some really cool functionality with it...so I am very comfortable with it.  I also beleive the future of the web will continue on the current client-side path.

**However...**

The next challenge seems to be coming in the form of various controller frameworks: [**KnockoutJS**](http://knockoutjs.com/), [**BackboneJS**](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/), [**SproutCore**](http://www.sproutcore.com/), [**JavaScriptMVC**](http://javascriptmvc.com/) (the list goes on).

Additonally, there are some great [**AMD Loader**](http://unscriptable.com/index.php/2011/04/27/using-amd-loaders-to-write-and-manage-modular-javascript/) tools for use like [**RequireJS**](http://requirejs.org/) or [**LabJS**](http://labjs.com/) etc. However, jQuery now has `define` and `then` capabilities baked-in.

**It's getting harder-and-harder to keep track of it all...**

And now, my task seems to be to evaluate/decide-on a strategic-direction for using some form of either an MVC or MVVM framework client-side...but I have so many questions.

- Where does [**JQuery**](http://jquery.com/) **fit-in** with the various controller-frameworks mentioned above?
- Is [**JQuery**](http://jquery.com/) **used alongside** each or do some of them have their own '[**JQuery**](http://jquery.com/)-styled version' baked-in?
- Are tools like [**RequireJS**](http://requirejs.org/) **still needed** if you implement one of the various controller-frameworks mentioned above?
- Does the `define` and `then` capabilities baked-into [**JQuery**](http://jquery.com/) **now supercede** the AMD Loader mentioned above?
- Which one seems most modular? (see notes below)

**NOTES:**
One thing I don't want in any future-framework is the requirement of having to take-in vast amounts of functionality that I don't use.  Meaning, I would rather use a framework that is truly modular. For example, to use jQuery UI you have to take-in a lot other core libraries that you might not actually use.

I will be experimenting with each one, but some REAL feedback would be great.  I've seen some 'similar' questions, but none have really answered the above skew.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is being answered in [**another forum**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122507/where-does-jquery-fit-in-with-frameworks-like-javascriptmvc-backbonejs-sproutc/122647#122647).  Please feel free to post all your answers there instead of this one.